# Largest subset of elements which don't share same labels

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of elements where each element has two labels (A and B). Is there any algorithm to compute the largest subset of elements such that for every two elements e1, e2 in the subset, e1.A ≠ e2.A and e1.B ≠ e2.B ?

Comment: I think it is related to the problem of finding the biggest connected component in a graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is exactly the [3D MATCHING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) problem. The first set is the A labels, the second sets are the elements themselves, and the third set are the B labels. A subset of elements with distinct A and B labels forms a 3D matching.

It is a well-known NP-hard problem: at this stage, mankind does not know any polynomial algorithm to solve it. But there is a very simple 3-approximation algorithm: start with an empty element set, then add some element (satisfying the constraints) until it is no longer possible. You end up with a set of elements which is at most 3 times smaller than the largest possible one (see the wikipedia page).